# External views are slowing down rendering in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I am using couples views to format my data in each loop. Let's get a closer look at my code:

Template:

```
{{#each controller.positions}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{position}}</td>
    <td class="url">{{url}}</td>
    {{#each days}}
      {{#view App.DaysView changed=data.change}}
      <td {{bind-attr class="view.change"}}>{{data.position}}</td>
      {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

View:

```
App.DaysView = Ember.View.extend({
    changed: 0,
    change: function() {
        if(this.get('changed') > 0)
        {
            return 'down';
        }

        if(this.get('changed') < 0)
        {
            return 'up';
        }
    }.property()
});
```

I am trying to add class .down when data.position is upper zero and ".up" class when data.position is below zero. **It works fine but very slow**. The reason of slowing down is using external views. How can I improve me code? Should I move logic to controller and use conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything which could slow down your app. If you are showing thousands of records could be a problem, but I guess this is not your case.

I think you could use an unique html element on this way:

```
App.DaysView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'td',
  classNameBindings: ['up', 'down'],
  up: Ember.computed.gt('changed', 0),
  down: Ember.computed.lt('changed', 0),
  changed: 0

});
```

Comment: I have about 1 000 records in my loop. Your solution works much faster. Thanks.

Comment: There is also an experimental group helper.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each. Give it a try, maybe it helps.